# Probability question: Does independence of family of events imply the independence of subfamily?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In particular, if 
$$P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n) = P(A_1) \times \cdots \times  P(A_n),$$
does it follow that 
$$P(A_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_j}) = P(A_{i_1}) \times \cdots \times  P(A_{i_j})$$ 
where $i_1, \ldots , i_j$ are permutations of some $j$ natural numbers less or equal to $n$? If not, does the independence of the family imply the independence of two events in the family?

Comment: Yes, any subfamily is independent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you give me a proof?

Answer (score 0):

From $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ it cannot be concluded that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

However from the data that the events $A,B,C$ are mutually independent (which is a stronger condition) it can be concluded that the events $A,B$ are independent.

Actually it follows directly from the definiton of "mutually independent events" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events)).